# BOOST: How to implement a null named_mutex?

Tags: c++, boost

I sometimes need a "null" implementation of named_mutex(i.e. always succeeds and does nothing).

Is there is such implementation ? If not, what's the recommended way to implement?

Comment: @GMan:using a scoped lock- scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(*_mutex, second_clock::universal_time() + seconds(2))

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a class with empty definitions?

```
class named_mutex
{
public:
    named_mutex(create_only_t, const char *) {}
    named_mutex(open_or_create_t, const char *) {}
    named_mutex(open_only_t, const char *) {}
    ~named_mutex() {}

    void unlock() {}
    void lock() {}
    bool try_lock() {}
    bool timed_lock(const boost::posix_time::ptime &) {}

    static bool remove(const char *) {}
};
```

Use an instance of this as your `named_mutex` and it's like it never existed.